# Error: ‘std::function isinf’ redeclared as different kind of symbol

Tags: c++, function

I would like to create a function that checks if my `x` is a number.

But after only one line of code, I got an error which I don't understand. Where do I redeclare my function?

```
std::function<bool(double)> isinf = [](double x) { return std::isnan(x); };
```

```
main.cpp:17:29: error: ‘std::function isinf’ redeclared as different kind of symbol
 std::function<bool(double)> isinf = [](double x) { return std::isnan(x); };

/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/mathcalls.h:201:1:
 note: previous declaration ‘int isinf(double)’


__MATHDECL_1 (int,isinf,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
```

Comment: The standard library has a function named `isinf`. The compiler is complaining because that name is used in two different ways, one in your code and one in the standard library headers. Besides, why would `isinf` return `isnan`? A NaN is not an infinity.

Comment: Can you show us a bit more code - do you have a line like `#include <bits/c++>` or similar? Also, what platform/compiler are you using?

Comment: I put that one line of code into a program, and it compiled without errors. Often, a compiler will detect an error at a different location than the actual error. Please include a [mcve] demonstrating the compile error.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I didn't know that there is already a function named isinf. After renamed isinf everything works fine. I randomly picked up this function name and did't realize it may be in the standard library. I really appreciate your help.